# how to treat findstr input as a pure plain text in a bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in my bat file:

```
echo %%h|findstr /I "{" > nul & if not errorlevel 1 (
```

%%h is the input for my findstr command. But some times the %%h contains some command as well which makes the bat file to generate errors. I just want findstr to treat its input (%%h) as plain text. How can I do it? Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!
The answer is: 
enclose the %%h with double quotation! 
:)

```
echo "%%h"|findstr /I "{" > nul & if not errorlevel 1 (
```